# AJAX posting a list doesnt work

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I am trying to post an array of names to a web service. The following is my code written in JQuery AJAX:

```
var poster=[1,2,3]
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
traditional:true,
url:"/post",
data: {'poster':poster},
dataType: 'JSON',
cache: false,
success: function(result){console.log(result);}
});
```

What happens is, only '3'(the last element in the array) is getting POSTED. My console.log also returns `Object{poster:"3"}`. I tried everything from adding traditional keyword to making the data anonymous like data: {'':poster} and so on. Nothing worked. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `JSON.stringify()`

```
var dataToBePosted = { poster: [1, 2, 3] };
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:"/post",
    data: JSON.stringify(dataToBePosted),
    dataType: 'JSON',
    cache: false,
    success: function(result){console.log(result);}
});
```

Comment: Hi @Yasser can your code support passing of JSON formatted string?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery turns them into three `POST` arguments, like `poster[]=1&poster[]=2&poster[]=3`. You should receive three `poster[]` arguments on the server side. First holds 1, second - 2 and third - 3. I guess you are retreiving only the last one, so you get only 3. What you need is to get all of them.

Comment: How do I get all of them. My list can expand too

Comment: It depends on which language and framework you use on the server side.

Comment: No. In the client side I am using console.log to figure out what gets posted. Only the last one gets posted

Comment: I've checked my solution in the Chrome console. All three are posted. I would send you the screenshot but it's not allowed in the comments.

Comment: Hi Tim. Mine didnt work unless i did what @Yasser suggested. Can you please try that one? It works perfectly well :)

Comment: Yeah it works. But it sends a string '[1,2,3]'. Mine is sending three post arguments, which should be easily processed on the server side with no parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
    var poster=[1,2,3];
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           traditional:true,
           url:"/post",
           data: {'poster':JSON.stringify(poster)},
           dataType: 'JSON',
           cache: false,
           success: function(data){
             console.log(data);
           }
    });
```

or

```
       var poster=[1,2,3];
        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               traditional:true,
               url:"/post",
               data: 'poster='+JSON.stringify(poster),
               dataType: 'JSON',
               cache: false,
               success: function(data){
                 console.log(data);
               }
        });
```